# Textile: line breaks in table cells

Tags: textile

How can I get the following with Texttile:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       Model:
    </td>
    <td>
       Ford<br/>
       BMW<br/>
       VM
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So where one cell has multiple lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can include well formatted HTML code in textile:

```
|Model:||Ford <br/> BMW <br/> VM||
```

Just try it on [textile.thresholdstate.com](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/).

As the above homepage says: HTML code should be wrapped besides `==`, this way calling the following would result in the required output:

```
|Model:||Ford ==<br>== BMW ==<br>== VM||
```

Both method works for me :)

Besides this obvious way you could build a table with colspan, so not using manual breaklines but having the second column have 3 rows while only one in the first:

```
|/3. Models: | Ford |
| BMV |
| VM |
```

Resulting in:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Models: </td>
            <td> Ford </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> BMV </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> VM </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you meant rowspan instead of colspan. That's how I solved it in the end.

Comment: That is right @Pickels, it was to be rowspan, thanks for feedback! I am happy this could work out for you. If you liked my answer please upvote/accept.

Answer (score 3):

```
|Model:|Ford
BMW
VM|
```

should do.. however *might* be depending on the textile parser you are using.

Regarding the above mentioned [textile.thresholdstate.com](http://textile.thresholdstate.com) : afaik they use a rather outdated textile parser.. the current PHP implementation (as used in textpattern) can be found at [github.com/netcarver/textile](https://github.com/netcarver/textile), with it's test site being here: [textile.sitemonks.com](http://textile.sitemonks.com)